# How to make a side ribbon style for a card block

Tags: html, css

I need help with adding the "Completed" status for a block as per the screenshot below.

[Click to view the sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSK6K.png)

Currently, it's just a div with the below configs.

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column; align-items: center; justify-content: center; ">
  <img src="./PCIBT - Pacific Coast Institute of Business &amp; Technology_files/marketing_essentials.jpg "><a href="# ">Marketing Essentials</a>
  <img src="./PCIBT - Pacific Coast Institute of Business &amp; Technology_files/human_resource_tile_pic.jpg "><a href="# ">Human Resource Management</a>
  <img src="./PCIBT - Pacific Coast Institute of Business &amp; Technology_files/pm_fundamentals.jpg "><a href="# ">Project Management Fundamentals</a>
</div>
```

Comment: please add the html, css in the snippet as far as you have done.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. You could try adding a before pseudo element and using clip path or think about linear-gradient background image for example.